# How to only insert unique data into an access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database that I need to update only if my information is unique.  Is there a simple sql statement to accomplish this?  Will 'insert ignore' work with access?

Example: I have the info stored in an array ('bob','34','hair').  If my database contains a record that matches on those three columns I would not want it to be inserted.  If it was found to be unique I would like it to be inserted.

I am writing this in cold fusion but just cant seem to get the sql right.

Comment: what is your table structure? Are you doing the lookup in code fusion or in ms access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing an insert, do a select for those values.  If you don't get a record back then you know it is safe to insert.  Just use two separate queries, one for the check, and if no record found, then the insert.

Comment: Sounds pretty solid I will try it out.  Thanks!

Comment: no problem. Don't forget to accept if it works out and let me know if it doesn't and ill try to help.

Comment: Also, fyi, its coldfusion not cold fusion.  One is a programming language, the other is a theoretical physics experiment!

Answer (score 3):

A unique index is always a good idea if a field or set of fields should be unique. If you have a unique index in Access on the three fields, an insert will fail.

It is possible is to create a single query that only inserts a record where a matched record is not found, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Shows (ForeName,Reviews,Musical)
SELECT "bob" As ForeName,"34" As Reviews,"hair" As Musical
FROM (SELECT Count(*) As  ExistsCount 
      FROM Shows 
      WHERE ForeName = "bob",Reviews = "34",Musical = "hair")  AS  e
WHERE e.ExistsCount=0
```

Comment: this is also a rock solid solution

Comment: It's very expensive in a number of ways to append data that will be discarded based on index collisions. In fact, it can lead to bloat in the database and it can use up Autonumber values. I would never do it that way, and would always write my SQL to eliminate the duplicates before insertion.

Comment: Okay, but it is still a good idea to have a unique index if a set of fields should be unique. I will edit.

Comment: Oh, I was not meaning at all to criticize the suggestion for having appropriate indexing. To me, that goes without saying!

Comment: I think it's interesting you implemented your SQL with a correlated subquery. I'd be much more likely to do it with an OUTER JOIN, but it can get hairy to do that with ad hoc multiple values being inserted.